# `@PreAuthorize` with spring-native triggers packaging error: `repeated interface: org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy`

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I'm trying to build native images for spring-boot apps in a maven [multi-module project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/lifix/tree/master/api).

As soon as I decorate a @Controller method with `@PreAuthorize`, native image generation fail with the message below.

Following spring-native samples, I tryed both with (as done in `security-method-class-proxies`) and without (as done in `security-method`) `@AotProxyHint` on application class, but this made no difference.

The error:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Error parsing dynamic proxy configuration in file:/workspace/META-INF/native-image/org.springframework.aot/spring-aot/proxy-config.json:
[INFO]     [creator]     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: repeated interface: org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy
[INFO]     [creator]     Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option DynamicProxyConfigurationResources.
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute native-image layer
[INFO]     [creator]     error running build
[INFO]     [creator]     exit status 1
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

Any clue why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out two things about this error:

1. as soon as `@PreAuthorize` targets a class member (not an interface), configuration must provide an `@AotProxyHint(targetClass = ..., proxyFeatures = ProxyBits.IS_STATIC)` for this class
2. there is bug on Windows about that declared in [spring-native issues](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/issues/950)